# Perform a get request from a service worker based from Angular

Tags: javascript, reactjs, angular, rxjs

Im migrating over from Angular5. In angular5 i was using services, now im trying to use react.

Im trying to call a function from globalService.js, and do something with it in app.js.

so far i got this error:

```
TypeError: _globalService__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_5__.default.PerformRequest is not a function
```

**test data:**

app contains:

```
import doSomething from "./globalService";
        console.log("doing a request",doSomething.PerformRequest('test'));
```

globalservice:

```
const PerformRequest = function(data) {
console.log("data is:",data);

}

export default PerformRequest;
```

**test data end**

**Ideally im trying to translate my angular code to react code.**
here is my angular old code:

app call:

```
  click() {

    this.GlobalService.PerformRequest('/crime').pipe(takeUntil(this._destroyed$)).subscribe((data:any) => {
      DO SOMETHING WITH DATA HERE
    });
  }
```

globalservice call:

```
  PerformRequest(params) {
    console.log(this.baseURL + params);
    return this.http.get(this.baseURL + params,this.options)
      .pipe(
        //catchError(this.handleError)
      );
  }
```

**Q1:** What am i doing wrong in my first example above?

**Q2:** How would i rewrite my angular data to react language so i can use it to call from a component the same was as im calling it?

Comment: could you post any fiddle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Q1: Your import is not correct, it should be

```
import PerformRequest from './globalService';
```

if you keep the globalService the way it's currently return. If you do want something like a service you could export an object containing all the methods.

```
export default {
    PerformRequest,
};
```

Q2:

I'd suggest you look into [hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html) to reproduce what you already have as a service.

You could do something like that:
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';

```
// define a hook
const useFetchUrl = (url) => {
    // useState are used to store some state
    const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true);
    const [data, setData] = useState();

    // useEffect is done for side effect
    useEffect(() => {
        fetch(url)
          .then(resp => resp.json())
          .then(data => setData(data);
    }, [url];

    return {
      isLoading,
      data,
    };
}

const Component = () => {
  const { loading, data } = useFetchUrl('/some/url');

  if (!loading) {
      return <div>Loading...</div>;
  }

  return <pre>{JSON.stringify(data)}</pre>;
};
```

[swr](https://github.com/vercel/swr#data-fetching) is a nice library that provides you with hooks you could use to do the same kind of thing without having to write your own custom hooks and dealing with some more complicated cases.